# What's the difference between XCTAssert and XCTAssertTrue?

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, xctest

What's the difference between XCTAssert and XCTAssertTrue? They seem to be doing the same thing, if so why do we need both?

Comment: different semantics. I use `XCTAssertTrue`/`XCTAssertFalse` on `BOOL` and `XCTAssert` for everything else

Comment: @BryanChen There is no different semantics whatever. They are 100% identical.

Comment: @matt Code perform the same thing doesn't always mean they have same semantics.

Comment: @BryanChen XCTAssert still means you are asserting the condition in it to be true, so technically it has the same semantic as XCTAssertTrue, no?

Comment: @Boon at least _I_ am reading `XCTAssertTrue(var)` as `XCTAssert(var == true)`. and yes it doesn't make much difference

Comment: @BryanChen It isn't that it performs the same thing. It literally _is_ the same thing. The semantics are identical - they are synonyms.

Comment: The distinction is important in terms of readability. I prefer `XCTAssert` where my tests use a comparison operator, and `XCTAssertTrue/False` where the return value of the tested method is boolean. Examples: `XCTAssert(hasSomething() == false)` or `XCTAssert(getThings().count == 5)` vs. `XCTAssertFalse(hasSomething())`

Comment: But @DavidJames, in your example `XCTAssertFalse` *is* a different semantic than `XCTAssert` because it's the inverse. The difference is between `XCTAssert` and `XCTAssertTrue`.  The former asserts something is true whereas the latter is totally different in that it asserts something is true! ;)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You are correct to suggest that there is redundancy here. They are in fact *absolutely* identical - that is, under the hood they both evaluate to one and the same macro, `_XCTPrimitiveAssertTrue`.

Comment: See _XCTestAssertions.h_ for confirmation.

Comment: Hmmm... DRY doesn't count in unit test frameworks?  ;-)

Comment: The functionally equivalent synonyms do provide flexibility for writing readable code.  `XCTAssertTrue(someStateVariable)` benefits from the more verbose `XCTAssertTrue`.  `XCTAssert(a == b)` reads clearly with the more compact `XCTAssert`.  Use whichever enhances the statement's readability.

Comment: You should consider using `XCTAssertEqual(a, b)` for case `XCTAssert(a == b)` because `XCTAssertEqual` can provide better logs.